# How to break and continue a try-catch inside a while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, ldap, try-catch, thread-sleep

There is a need to connect to LDAP using LDAPConnection using Java in a try-catch. When the initial connection cannot be established, i now want to create some logic to reattempt the connection after 1 minute for a max of 3 attempts.

Current logic:

```
try {
      connect = new LDAPConnection(...);
} catch (LDAPException exc) {
      //throw exception message
}
```

Desired logic:

```
int maxAttempts = 3, attempts=0;
while(attempt < maxAttempts) {
     try {
         connect = new LDAPConnection(...);
         /*if connection can be established then break from loop, but keep connection alive*/
         break;
     } catch(LDAPException exc) {
            if(attempt == (maxAttempts-1)) {
                 //throw exception message
             }
             continue;
      }

     Thread.sleep(1000);
     attempt++;
}
```

Is the code in my desired logic correct? I also wanted to be sure my break and continue statements are in the correct location in the loop.

Comment: Remove the 'continue', otherwise you have infinite attempts - since you never get to 'attempt++'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `continue` to avoid an infinite loop.
And since you have a counter, use a for-loop instead of while:

```
int maxAttempts = 3;
for(int attempts = 0; attempts < maxAttempts; attempts++) {
    try {
         connect = new LDAPConnection(...);
         /*if connection can be established then break from loop, but keep connection alive*/
         break;
    } catch(LDAPException exc) {
         if(attempt == (maxAttempts-1)) {
             //throw exception message
             throw exc;
         }
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```